# pygame on python 2.7 using PYGAME_WINDOW.screen.fill on macOS Mojave v10.14.6

Tags: python, python-2.7, pygame

I am creating a pygame window using the python 2.7.16 interpreter on macOS Mojave.
It loads with the appropriate window size and location, but it does not add a background color, and I am not able to draw shapes on this background.The pygame window remains a blank white surface without any change in color no matter what is drawn to the draw surface and the background.

The screen should be red, but no matter what values I pass to the `self.screen.fill((int, int, int))` method, it does not change color.

**constants.py**

```
pygameWindowWidth = 1500
pygameWindowDepth = 1500
```

**realTimeDraw.py**

```
from pygameWindow import PYGAME_WINDOW

pygameWindow = PYGAME_WINDOW()

print(pygameWindow)

while True:
    pygameWindow.Prepare()
    pygameWindow.Draw_Black_Circle(100,100)
    pygameWindow.Reveal()
```

**pygameWindow.py file**

```
import pygame
from constants import *

class PYGAME_WINDOW:
    def __init__(self):
        pygame.init()
        self.width = pygameWindowWidth
        self.depth = pygameWindowDepth
        self.screen = pygame.display.set_mode((pygameWindowWidth, pygameWindowDepth))

    def Prepare(self):
        self.screen.fill((255, 0, 0))

    def Reveal(self):
        pygame.display.update()

    def Draw_Black_Circle(self, x, y):
        pygame.draw.circle(self.screen, (255, 0, 0), (x, y), 45, 0)
        pygame.display.update()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To make the program work, you've to handle the events which are pending in the event queue, by either [`pygame.event.pump()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/event.html#pygame.event.pump) or [`pygame.event.get()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/event.html#pygame.event.get). e.g.:

```py
pygameWindow = PYGAME_WINDOW()

run = True
while run:

    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            run = False

    pygameWindow.Prepare()
    pygameWindow.Draw_Black_Circle(100,100)
    pygameWindow.Reveal()
```

Comment: That works!!! But do you know why color was only changed in terminal not in pycharm?